# Fix space in path from find command

Tags: zsh, cp

I would like to copy many files with the below command.

```
 cp `find /Volumes/DATA/ -name "*.app" -depth 1 2> /dev/null` /Volumes/VMWare/img/
```

But that doesn't work because if it finds a space then it interprets it as the end of the order.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

First, find can do something with its results; look at the `-exec {}` flag. You can do something like:

```
find /Volumes/DATA/ -name "*.app" -depth 1 2> /dev/null -exec cp '{}' /Volumes/VMWare/img/ \;
```

Notice the single quotes around the file placeholder "{}."

You could also use a pipe with xargs.

Comment: The single quotes around `{}` won't do anything special. `find` already knows how to pass the argument without any shell doing splitting on the value.

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't know, I've run into problems before and the man page shows it in the examples, e.g.: find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;

Comment: It will only be an issue in non-`sh` shells, like `csh` and `tcsh`. I'm pointing this out specifically because you make it sound like adding the single quotes is important. It's not.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, `` `...` `` like the modern form `$(...)` splits on characters of `$IFS`, which by default includes SPC, TAB, NL and NUL.

Of those, only NUL cannot occur in a file path, so you'd need:

```
IFS=$'\0'
cp $(find /Volumes/DATA/ -name "*.app" -depth 1 -print0 2> /dev/null) /Volumes/VMWare/img/
```

Or, instead of using the implicit word splitting done by `$(...)` using a global parameter, use an explicit splitting operator:

```
cp ${(0)"$(find /Volumes/DATA/ -name "*.app" -depth 1 -print0 2> /dev/null)"} /Volumes/VMWare/img/
```

But in any case, using `find` here has no benefit whatsoever over:

```
cp /Volumes/DATA/*.app(D) /Volumes/VMWare/img/
```

(here using the `D` glob qualifier so it also includes hidden files like `find` does, though it's likely you'd want to skip them anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Use `-print0` with `find` to null terminate file names and feed this output to `xargs` with `-0` to instruct `xargs` that file names from standard input are null terminated. And use `-I` to replace strings in the initial arguments.

`find /Volumes/DATA/ -name '*.app' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I fn cp fn /Volumes/VMWare/img/`